# "frightened 'by' spiders" vs. "frightened 'of' spiders" in AmEng

Tags: grammar, american-english, colloquialisms, prepositional-phrases, dialects

Could you explain the difference between these two sentences:

> *I'm frightened BY spiders.*
>
> *I'm frightened OF spiders.*

Obviously both are used in American English in the sense "have a fear of spiders/be afraid of spiders," but is one more correct than the other?

Please, consider this sourced example:

> *I have been **frightened by** spiders since I was very young. For the following three reasons, spiders will never be pets of mine. The first reason that I am scared of spiders is their appearance.*
>
> *Yet take a random group of people and it is more than likely there will be among them those who are **frightened by** spiders, and those who are scared of heights.*

[Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22frightened+by+spiders%22&biw=491&bih=322&prmd=vin&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigvO-C1KHLAhUE0xQKHVslDJsQ_AUICygG&dpr=2)

[Ngram AmEng](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=frightened+by+spiders%2Cfrightened+by+snakes%2Cfrightened+of+snakes%2Cfrightened+of+spiders&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrightened%20by%20spiders%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrightened%20by%20snakes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrightened%20of%20snakes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrightened%20of%20spiders%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Frightened _of_ is used to show a general or hypothetical state (... snakes /  horses / an avalanche happening / floods ...). Frightened _by_ is usually used to address something more specific / immediate (... this enormous spider that's just gone under the sofa / his sudden change / this news / the level of the river ...).

Comment: "Scared of heights" from your example. Does "scared by heights" mean the same?

Comment: This will be interesting. http://www.englishgrammar.org/afraid-frightened-scared/

Comment: @EdwinAshworth +1 True. Incidenally, both the OP's examples go with *of*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both expressions appear to have currency according to a very quick look through the Google periscope.  The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=scared+by%2C+scared+of&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cscared%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bscared%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BScared%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cscared%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bscared%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BScared%20of%3B%2Cc0") chart shows an interesting result, suggesting that **scared of** emerged in the mid to late 19th C., which is contemporary with examples offered up by  couple of online dictionaries: Mark Twain's *Adventures of Tom Sawyer*. It's not quite a "smoking pen", but it's interesting all the same.

**Scared by** has a robust earlier history, but seems to have lost preeminence, at least in the unblinking eyes of Ngram, to **Scared of**.

The usual lexicons will define "scared," but seem mum on the subject of trailing prepositions.

Which brings us to the tags "American English" and "Colloquialism" - i.e. the world of anecdote and opinion.

A flight through today's Googleverse shows that people are **scared of** Donald Trump's candidacy, self-driving cars, and losing the fight with cancer. (*Arachnophobes had better move over - it's a scary world out there.*) Similarly, people in G-space have been **scared by** things: intruders, pit bulls and kids in Halloween costumes (well, sorta).

It's an observation backed by lifetime personal usage that one may be **scared of** things in the abstract, in the future, or on general principles, while **scared by** seems to denote an experience that is more immediate, proximate, and fang-baringly perilous.

Interestingly, more people seem **scared of** things than **by** them, at least if we bet the farm on Ngrams.

*The two phrases aren't quite interchangeable, although they seem to be interchanged with a measure of indifferent impunity in the US, where most speakers are not scared of or by grammar books, rules, or curmudgeons who wield them.*

Comment: @elian http://www.englishgrammar.org/afraid-frightened-scared/